# Auto generate radio button, from .txt file in intelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

So is it possible to make a radio button, where it auto generate from a txt file?

so lets say i got a .txt file with 10 words, i want those 10 words to each make a radio button, and if i add a new word to the txt file, it shows up

Any know how to do this or where to find some help :) ?

Or would you use something other then a radio button?

Hope some can help me out.

Comment: Divide and conquer: split your problem up in multiple, easy to solve parts. In your case: Read the file, parse the line, create a radio button, place it in the container. If you run into specific problems please ask a precise question and show the code you used.

Comment: What do you mean by "in IntelliJ"? Where do you want the radio buttons to appear, and what do you want them to do?